# Submitting data from different fields depending on selection of dropdown - laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, dropdown

My form contains a dropdown were yes or no can be selected. If yes is selected a dropdown will appear. When no is selected an input text filed will appear. However, this function is working but I can't submit my data. I can only submit my data when one of the "Dropdown 2" or "input 1" is removed (see code which field I mean).

If I submit the data I got the following error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` . I think it is because of the fact that I have two fields that can send data. This both fields (hidden and displayed field) send data then as an array instead of sending data to the controller from the field that is diplayed. How can this be solved. Could someone help me?

Thansk

```js
function displayField() {
      if (document.getElementById("isYes").selected) {
        document.getElementById("ifyes").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("check").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("ifno").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ifyes").required = true;
      } else if (document.getElementById("isNo").selected) {
        document.getElementById("ifno").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("check").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("ifyes").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ifno").required = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("ifno").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ifyes").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("check").style.display = "none";
      }
    };
```

```html
<form action="/tests" method="POST">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="p-1">
        <label class="p-2" for="type">Type </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="flex-fill p-2">
        <select name="type" class="form-control" onchange="displayField()" required>
          <option></option>
          <option id="isYes">Yes</option>
          <option id="isNo">No</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="p-1">
        <label id="check" style="display: none;" class="p-2" for="select">Select</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="flex-fill p-2">
# Dropdown 2
        <select name="select" class="form-control" id="ifyes" style="display: none;" >


          <option>IC</option>
          <option>PD</option>
          <option>RB</option>
          <option>VDQ</option>
          <option>VDS</option>
        </select>
# input 1
        <input style="display: none;" id="ifno" type="text" class="form-control input-text" placeholder="select" name="select">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 offset-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="margin: 10px;">New </button>
  </div>
</div>  
</form>
```

Comment: Do one thing. On document ready have all the field as required so that user can't able to submit without filling the required field. Now on select, the option removes required from other hidden field and have required on the visible field.

Comment: Thanks for the required solution. But how do I solve the error I then got ```htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is disabling fields when the field is hidden. You can use therefore

```
document.getElementById('id_of_field_to_disable').disabled = true
```

Here [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658588/how-to-submit-only-one-of-hide-show-fields-data-when-required-laravel) to a similar problem with a solution.

Also, check-in your controller's validation if your field is indicated as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have also the same problem that form is not submit. but using below code 
this works well for me.You should change according to your code.    
<!-- This is my html code -->
 <select id="imA" name="imA" onchange="addfield();" required="">
                <option value="">I am a ...</option>
                <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
                <option value="student">Student</option>
 </select>

 <div id="showField">
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function addfield(){
    var evalue = $('#imA').val();
    if(evalue == 'student'){            
        $('#showField').html('<input type="text" placeholder="  Enrollment 
 No." name="eno" id="eno" required>');
    }
    else{
        $('#showField').html('');
    }      

}
```